# ViewChild is undefined on browser back

Tags: angular

HTML:

```
<div class="row no-gutters nav-menu" *ngIf="items.length" #stickyMenu [class.sticky]="sticky">
</div>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild("stickyMenu", { static: false }) public menuElement: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;


  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      if (this.menuElement) {
        this.elementPosition = this.menuElement.nativeElement.offsetTop;
      }
}
```

But menuElement is always undefined on browser back, works fine in other cases. Any idea guys?

Comment: I guess there's a typo. `#sticky` should be `#stickyMenu` or `@ViewChild("stickyMenu", { static: false })` should be `@ViewChild("sticky', { static: false }) `

Comment: yes, updated :)